# Rails for web-game development

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, html5-canvas

guys! I`m collecting info about writting a game for web using Rails back-end. 
Are there any gems or something for game development with HTML5 and Javascript?

Unfortunatelly I've found very few info on it. Once I've used an gmaps-4-rails gem that helped me very much... not bothering with JS is great, so now i`m looking for a gem making use of some js-game-frameworks.

Comment: What kind of game are you trying to make?

Comment: I wouldn't expect to find here anything helpful. Reasons: Rails is a multi-page environment, where games on the web are normally single-page applications; roundtrip of rails (client - internet - server - database) kills a game; Rails is MVC with a database for storage, and nothing will be needed in a web-game.

Comment: @mliebelt, I wouldnt' be so sure. It would be perfectly fine with a turn based strategy game. Besides you can always go with a single page with ajax, and Rails could drive the backend with REST and JSON.

Comment: I`m making a single player (for now) arcade with JS+html5 (Hope to be angry birds like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases you'll use rails backend only for fetching and saving some data (user saves for example). So, you can use all possibilities that REST gives to you.
But...it seems that you don't really need anything special gems for this purposes (activerecord and routing already bundled with rails ㋛).

Also for developing html5 game you can use one of the box2d ports to javascript (or write your own game framework using only canvas's methods).

Answer (score 1):

the rails part @r-k cover it 
but the game part you can give  [createjs](http://createjs.com/#!/CreateJS)  a try to save a lot of time building your game